# How to get CAShapeLayer to work with constraints with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, cashapelayer

i got this in viewdidload

```
rectShape1 = CAShapeLayer()

rectShape1.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
rectShape1.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rectShape1.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .BottomLeft | .TopRight, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).CGPath
redview.layer.addSublayer(rectShape1)


var constTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: redview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(constTop)

var constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: redview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
redview.addConstraint(constH)

var constW = NSLayoutConstraint(item: redview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
redview.addConstraint(constW)

constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: redview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(constH)
rectShape1.frame = redview.bounds
```

and this in didlayoutsubviews

```
            self.rectShape1.frame = self.redview.bounds
```

i have similar stuff with gradientLayer and i works fine, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `rectShape1.bounds.size` is {0,0} at the time you create the bezier path. Remove the line where you create the path from `viewDidLoad`, and move it to after you set the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.rectShape1.frame = self.redview.bounds
        rectShape1.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rectShape1.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .BottomLeft | .TopRight, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).CGPath
    }
```

Comment: is it possible to do this on a `UIView` subclass? i.e. by overriding `layoutSubviews`, as it doesn't seem to work this way